# Polymorphism uses

Tags: java, polymorphism

I'm trying to understand why one would use polymorphism in java. All I can think of is that it aids in keeping object types similar for storage. For example the parent class employee could have managers, drivers, cashiers, etc. all stored as one type to avoid using generics. Is this accurate and am I missing another use?

Comment: For starters, that sounds like a really insane design; having one model represent more than it should.

Comment: Polymorphism is one of the central tenets of object oriented design.  A Google search for something like "why use polymorphism" yields *many* results.  You've almost kind of sort of talked about one possible example of it, but that is by no means the extent of it.

Comment: So what is the purpose of polymorphism then?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082640/benefit-of-polymorphism and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064409/why-to-use-polymorphism are good to read up on

Comment: @JacobRicci: The purpose of polymorphism is to allow one object to be perceived in multiple different forms (types).  In your example, a single instance of a `Manager` can be perceived as a `Manager`, as an `Employee`, or as an `Object`, depending on the need of the code acting upon it.