# Passing Variables to Extended Class and Calling Methods

Tags: java, variables, methods

I am at a complete loss right now. I am trying to develop a program that will display the `Months`, `Account #`, and `Balance` of two savings accounts and update the `Balance` as interest on the accounts is accrued:

- For the first account 10,002 interest is accrued monthly with a yearly interest rate of 1.2%.
- For the second account 10,003 interest is accrued quarterly with a yearly interest rat of 4%.

I have to design four individual classes in order to do this.  `SavingsAccount`, `SavingsAccountDriver`, `FlexibleSavingsAccount`, and `CDSavingsAccount`. `SavingsAccount` is the parent class of both `FlexibleSavingsAccount` and `CDSavingsAccount`. `SavingsAccountDriver` is the Main class.

In `SavingsAccount` I have a method `setAnnualInterestRate()` that is called in `SavingsAccountDriver`.  This method sets the interest rate for each account.  The problem I am having is passing this value to the extended classes `FlexibleSavingsAccount` and `CDSavingsAccount` so that I can update the balance by adding the interest rate for each account. If anyone could please assist me on how this is done I would greatly appreciate it.

**SavingsAccountDriver**:

```
public class SavingsAccountDriver {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        SavingsAccount saver1 = new SavingsAccount(10002, 2000); //create new SavingsAccount object
        SavingsAccount saver2 = new SavingsAccount(10003, 3000); //create new SavingsAccount object

        saver1.setAnnualInterestRate(.012); //sets AnnualInterestRate for 'saver1' object
        saver2.setAnnualInterestRate(.04); //sets AnnualInterestRate for 'saver2' object

        System.out.println("\nMonthly balances:\n");
        System.out.println("Month " + " Account# " + " Balance " + "      " + " Month " + " Account# " + " Balance ");
        System.out.println("----- " + " -------- " + " ------- " + "      " + " ----- " + " -------- " + " ------- ");


        System.out.println(saver1.getAccountNumber() + " / " + saver1.getBalance() + " / " + saver1.getInterest());
        System.out.println(saver2.getAccountNumber() + " / " + saver2.getBalance() + " / " + saver2.getInterest());

        /*for(int month = 0; month <= 12; month++) {
            switch(month) { // switch that outputs month, account number, and balance for both accounts (Some non-needed cases used to make output look cleaner)
                case 0:
                    System.out.println(month + "      " + saver1.getAccountNumber() + "     " + saver1.getBalance() + "         " + month + "      " + saver2.getAccountNumber() + "     " + saver2.getBalance());
                    break;
                case 4: 
                    saver1.addInterest();
                    //saver2.addInterest();

                    System.out.println(month + "      " + saver1.getAccountNumber() + "     " + saver1.getBalance() + "         " + month + "      " + saver2.getAccountNumber() + "     " + saver2.getBalance());
                    break;
                case 10:
                    saver1.addInterest();
                    //saver2.addInterest();

                    System.out.println(month + "     " + saver1.getAccountNumber() + "     " + saver1.getBalance() + "        " + month + "     " + saver2.getAccountNumber() + "     " + saver2.getBalance());
                    break;
                case 11:
                    saver1.addInterest();
                    //saver2.addInterest();

                    System.out.println(month + "     " + saver1.getAccountNumber() + "     " + saver1.getBalance() + "        " + month + "     " + saver2.getAccountNumber() + "     " + saver2.getBalance());
                    break;
                case 12:
                    saver1.addInterest();
                    //saver2.addInterest();

                    double totalBalance = saver1.getBalance() + saver2.getBalance();
                    System.out.println(month + "     " + saver1.getAccountNumber() + "     " + saver1.getBalance() + "        " + month + "     " + saver2.getAccountNumber() + "     " + saver2.getBalance());
                    break;
                default:
                    saver1.addInterest();
                    //saver2.addInterest();

                    System.out.println(month + "      " + saver1.getAccountNumber() + "     " + saver1.getBalance() + "        " + month + "      " + saver2.getAccountNumber() + "     " + saver2.getBalance());
                    break;
            }
        }*/
    }
}
```

**SavingsAccount**:

```
public class SavingsAccount {
    // variables specific to SavingsAccount class
    public double annualInterestRate;
    private final int ACCOUNT_NUMBER;
    public double balance;

    //constructor with account number and balance parameters
    public SavingsAccount(int account_number, double balance) {
        this.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = account_number;
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    //returns account number
    public int getAccountNumber() {
        return this.ACCOUNT_NUMBER;
    }

    //returns balance
    public double getBalance() {
        return this.balance;
    }

    //sets interest rate
    public void setAnnualInterestRate (double interestRate) {
        this.annualInterestRate = interestRate;
    }
}
```

**FlexibleSavingsAccount**:

```
public class FlexibleSavingsAccount extends SavingsAccount{

        public FlexibleSavingsAccount(int account_number, double balance) {
            super(account_number, balance);
        }

        //returns interest
        public double getInterest() {
            return annualInterestRate;  
        }
}
```

Comment: I don't think I understand. By extending a class, you should have access to the members of the parent class. Are you getting an error?

Comment: Yes. If you look at the last little bit of code i posted the getInterest() method should return the annualInterestRate of an object. In this case I have two objects of type SavingsAccount ('saver1' and 'saver2'). When I run the code I get the following error: cannot find symbol (referring to the section in the Main class saver1.getInterest() and saver2.getInterest().

Comment: You won't be able to run `getInterest()` from either of your `SavingsAccount` objects. `SavingsAccount` doesn't have `getInterest()` defined. If you want to use that method you have to initialize the object as `FlexibleSavingsAccount` or `CDSavingsAccount`

Comment: Why is this? Do I have to declare two more objects of type FlexibleSavingsAccount? I thought I would be able to use the SavingsAccount objects since the other classes are extended from this class.

Comment: I think you should read this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: you can use reference of SavingsAccount to point them. they will have their own implementation of calculating interest.

Comment: By declaring it as a `SavingsAccount`, all you (the compiler) know is that it is at least a `SavingsAccount` and `SavingsAccount` does not have a `getInterest()` method. It can't make any other assumptions.

Comment: `getInterest()` should be defined in `SavingsAccount`

Comment: may be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651066/why-use-type-substitution/25651192?noredirect=1#comment40082048_25651192) will help you.

Comment: Ok thank you all for the info. I will try it. I am new to Java if you cant tell haha. Thanks again.

Comment: You can declare getInterest() in SavingsAccount class, and then override it in the other classes

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add getInterest as an abstract method and declare SavingsAccount as abstract class.  then you will have the method known by the compiler to call and you will be forced in the subclasses to provide the proper implementation

Answer (score -1):

Your `getInterest()` method should be declared in your parent class - `SavingsAccount`- if you want to declare `saver1` and `saver2` as being of type `SavingsAccount`.

The way that you show, the method will only be available to classes declared as `FlexibleSavingsAccount`.

Since you declared them as `SavingsAccount` you only have access to that class' methods.

Child classes can access the methods of the parent but not the other way around.

Answer (score -1):

You have declared your instantiated savings accounts as type `SavingsAccount`. They will not have access to the method `getInterest()` since it is in the **child** class `FlexibleSavingsAccount`.

You need to instantiate them as the actual savings account that you wish them to actually be:

```
FlexibleSavingsAccount saver1 = new FlexibleSavingsAccount(10002, 2000); //create new FlexibleSavingsAccount object
```

Now `saver1` will be able to access `getInterest()`.

Extra idea:

What might be nicer is to code the parent `SavingsAccount` as an interface. You would then declare your `getInterest()` method in this interface, whilst leaving the details of what goes in the method to your children classes.

SavingsAccount:

```
public interface SavingsAccount {
    public int getAccountNumber();
    public double getBalance();
    public void setAnnualInterestRate (double interestRate);
 }
```

Then instantiate your accounts:

```
SavingsAccount saver1 = new FlexibleSavingsAccount(10002, 2000); //create new FlexibleSavingsAccount object
```

Note this has the added benefit that you declare your instances coded to the `SavingsAccount` interface which is always a nice idea for future proofing your code.

Comment: NOt sure what you mean by future proofing the code?  making an interface here looses the shared behavior that can be contained in a base class and forces the author to write the code twice with twice the maintenance if it needs to change and 2 times to enter something incorrectly?

Comment: Yep true an abstract base class instead of interface would handle this. I would probably do both an interface and an abstract base class.