# Choose method at runtime

Tags: java

I'm searching for an elegant and most of all "performance careful" way to use `laugh()` to call maleLaugh() or femaleLaugh(). There is a way to avoid a check each `laugh()` call?
I'm sure there is a design pattern for this.

```
public class Person {

    boolean gender;
    public Person(boolean gender){
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    public void laugh(){
        //--based on this.genderI call maleLaugh() or femaleLaugh()
    }
    public void maleLaugh(){
        System.out.println("muhahahaha");
    }
    public void femaleLaugh(){
        System.out.println("hihihihihi");
    }

}
```

Comment: Make `Person` an `interface`. Define two concrete types. `Male` and `Female`. Both implement `laugh()` (but differently).

Comment: Hint: caring about performance this way is very naive; and not helpful. Create good OO designs, and performance will follow; see here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064409/why-to-use-polymorphism

Comment: I'm sorry but charge with 'naiveness' without any clue of the project is kind of arrogant. I'm not learning OOP. I'm on a bigdata project. I'm just a little rusty with java.

Comment: If you'd really want a design pattern, you could use the strategy pattern.

Comment: [Polymorphism](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154577/polymorphism-vs-overriding-vs-overloading) is the answer.

Comment: Based off your question alone (i.e. ignoring OOP solutions for the time being), could you not just go `if (sex) { maleLaugh(); } else { femaleLaugh(); }`?

Comment: "I'm not learning OOP."  You asked for an elegant and performant solution.  That solution is OOP.