# Accessing a childs instance variables in superclass?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a method that writes data into a file in my `superclass(Employee)`. I need to write data of other employees in that method, but I am unsure how to access the **instance** variables in my **child classes** in order to accomplish this.

```
public class Employee
{
    protected String name;
    protected String employeeNum;
    protected String department;
    protected char type;
}  


public void writeData()
{
    BufferedWriter printer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("fileName"));
    //code here that adds Employee information, and Commission information to file
}  

public class Commission extends Employee 
{
    private int weeksStart;
    private double baseWeeklySalary;
    private double salesWeekly;
    private double totalSales;
    private double commissionRate;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Could you show your code, please! Your question is a bit confusing me

Comment: Updated my question to reflect what I am trying to do. I am not sure why I am receiving so many downvotes, I made the appropriate changes

Comment: Use method overrides to achieve polymorphic behavior. But what is the expected output for a Commission employee versus other types of employees or a generic employee instance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why to use Polymorphism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064409/why-to-use-polymorphism)

Comment: Alright so I just declare a global BufferedWriter in every parent/child class, and use method overrides to write the information I want to my file correct?

Comment: In the concept of inheritance a child object ***is alway*** a base object too... (a dog is an animal, a computer is a device etc etc)  looks and sounds weird to say that a commission is an employee(at least for the naming convention)

Answer (score 1):

`Commission` information is not accessible in superclass however you can override the `writeData()` in subclass which give you access to both `Employee` and `Commission` information.

```
@override
public void writeData()
{
    BufferedWriter printer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("fileName"));
    String data="name:"+name+","+"employeeNum:"+employeeNum+
           ","+"......"+","+"weeksStart:"+weeksStart;
    printer.write(data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! However, when I try to call writeData from my main, it writes only information of the last object tpe in my ArrayList, how do I get it to write once for every kind of Employee?

Comment: @ShahBari please add your main method so I can see whats happening.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a little trouble understanding your question, but if I'm correct you're wondering how to access the private members of Commission externally from  an instance of Employee. If that's correct, here:

The problem here lies in your use of [Polymorphism](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm) without properly structuring the Commission child class to allow access to the private members you want. Since the members are private, you cannot access them from any other class. You need to add get/set methods to the Commission class to access these private members. This lets them be accessed in strict manners while still being protected from external adjustment.

For instance, if you wanted to **set or get** the **commissionRate**, you could add methods into the commission class such as:

```
public void setCommissionRate(double newRate){
   //Confirming a non-negative input - set checks appropriately for your use
    if(newRate >= 0)  
        commissionRate = newRate;
}

public double getCommissionRate(){
    return commissionRate;
}
```

This will give access to other classes to the private members of your choosing. However, set methods are usually more scarce than get methods for private members since it can give *too much* access to external classes, and usually are either inherited or added in a constructor.

If accessing from an Employee instance, an overridden write method is necessary in the commission class to allow access to its members.

Hopefully I answered your primary question and this helps you out.